# Fast Ruby hash access

Tags: ruby, optimization

What is the fastest way to check if the all keys of a Ruby hash object point to empty arrays?

My current approach:

```
h = {"a" => [1,2,3], "b" => []}
var = "something" if h.values.flatten.size > 0
```

Another approach:

```
h = {"a" => [1,2,3], "b" => []}
var = "something" if h.values.flatten.empty?
```

Any other demonstrably faster way?

Comment: maybe just override the "setter" methods so it keeps track, on set time, if this property has now been violated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatten will cause your code to re-allocate a new, much larger buffer. You can skip the flatten like this:

```
h.values.all? &:empty?
```

Benchmarks:

```
Benchmark.measure {100000.times{ h.values.all? &:empty? }}
# =>   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.096073)

Benchmark.measure {100000.times{ h.values.flatten.empty? }}
# =>   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.143457)
```

Bigger benchmark, including `h.all? {|_,v| v.empty?}`

```
h = {}
(1...10000).each {|i| h[i] = []}  # Pathological case

Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ h.values.flatten.empty? }}
# =>   1.880000   0.000000   1.880000 (  1.882853)
Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ h.values.all? &:empty? }}
# =>   1.750000   0.000000   1.750000 (  1.748415)
Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ h.all? {|_,v| v.empty?} }}
# =>   4.140000   0.000000   4.140000 (  4.137548)
```

Comment: You don't need `h.values` at all: `h.all? { |_,v| v.empty? }`

Comment: The Symbol#to_proc seems to be slightly faster than a block, but not by much:
`irb(main):017:0> Benchmark.measure {100000.times{ h.all? {|_,v| v.empty?} }}
=>   0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.097628)`

Comment: I'm getting the opposite results. Perhaps you should use a larger `h`.

Comment: Can you post your benchmarks? I've included mine in the answer with a much larger `h` and it seems the block is even worse than `flatten`.

Comment: Yeah, `all?` does fall apart for the worst case, it does much better with the best case `h` though :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This gives me very similar performance,  `h.values.any?{|v| v.size != 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be greedy:

```
all_empty = true

h.each_value do |value|
  unless value.empty?
    all_empty = false
    break
  end
end
```

Benchmarks:

```
h = {}
(1...10000).each {|i| h[i] = []}

Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ h.values.flatten.empty? }}
=>   2.020000   0.000000   2.020000 (  2.026274)
Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ h.values.all? &:empty? }}
=>   1.750000   0.000000   1.750000 (  1.750908)
Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ h.all? {|_,v| v.empty?} }}
=>   3.570000   0.000000   3.570000 (  3.570945)
Benchmark.measure {1000.times{ <code above> }} # Worst case
=>   1.530000   0.000000   1.530000 (  1.529857)
```